# Shiny, When I make a query using reactive input variables I get an extra blank before the string I'm comparing too so my query doesn't get anything

Tags: r

I have this query

```
query<-paste("select disease_status,expvalue from taylor_21036,taylor_exp_21036 where geo_accession=id_geoacc and id_gpl like '",input$gen,"' order by'",input$gen,"'")
```

For some strange reason when I view the query I get:

```
select disease_status,expvalue from taylor_21036,taylor_exp_21036 where geo_accession=id_geoacc and id_gpl like ' hsa-let-7a ' order by ' hsa-let-7a '
```

**and extra blank is added in the left and in the right of my string**

How can I fix this?  Any idea?

I was getting mad because I didn't know why I was getting the error "need finite 'ylim' values" when I was trying to boxplot the data frame I got after doing a dbGetQuery with the query mentioned before but finally I found the problem,  the data frame was empty because my query doesn't get any rows because of the annoying extra blanks.

Please I will appreciate any advice.  Thank you!!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default separator between terms in paste is " " (space). If you don't want a separator then use paste0 or add the argument sep="" to your paste.

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked fine!!! I won't forget the argument sep, neither paste0 instead or paste.